# Pandas re-name dataframe headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having an issue with getting the correct headers in my pandas dataframes. Below is my full code. I would like to strip all the headers and then add my own at the very end.

```
import pandas as pd
#Ingest Data
df = pd.read_csv('C:/source/tradingdata/Kraken/XBTEUR.csv', names=['epoc', 'price', 'volume'])
#Convert from epoc to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoc'], unit='s')
#set index
df.set_index(df['datetime'], inplace=True, drop=False)
#resample OHLCV data
open_df = df.resample("1T").agg({'price': 'first'})
high_df = df.resample("1T").agg({'price': 'max'})
low_df = df.resample("1T").agg({'price': 'min'})
close_df = df.resample("1T").agg({'price': 'last'})
volume_df = df.resample("1T").agg({'volume': 'sum'})
#create new dataframe
new_df = pd.concat([open_df, high_df, low_df, close_df, volume_df], axis=1, keys=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
#only get bars where volume is > 0
new_df = new_df[new_df.volume > 0]
new_df.to_csv('C:/source/tradingdata/Kraken/XBTEUR_1Min.csv')
```

**Dataframe after new_df = pd.concat & the data I am exporting**

```
                        open     high      low    close    volume
                       price    price    price    price    volume
datetime                                                         
2021-03-31 23:55:00  49989.4  49998.7  49989.3  49989.3  0.033687
2021-03-31 23:56:00  49989.3  49989.3  49969.2  49969.3  0.013282
2021-03-31 23:57:00  49969.2  49969.2  49931.8  49969.2  1.197345
2021-03-31 23:58:00  49969.1  49969.2  49969.1  49969.2  0.122786
2021-03-31 23:59:00  50027.2  50049.9  50008.3  50008.3  1.271983
```

**What I want the headers to look like.**

```
datetime             open     high      low    close    volume
2021-03-31 23:55:00  49989.4  49998.7  49989.3  49989.3  0.033687
2021-03-31 23:56:00  49989.3  49989.3  49969.2  49969.3  0.013282
2021-03-31 23:57:00  49969.2  49969.2  49931.8  49969.2  1.197345
2021-03-31 23:58:00  49969.1  49969.2  49969.1  49969.2  0.122786
2021-03-31 23:59:00  50027.2  50049.9  50008.3  50008.3  1.271983
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have created hierarchical index using the passed keys at the `key=` parameter of the call to [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on top of the column index of previous aggregations, `MultiIndex` columns were created.

To remove the unwanted level of `MultiIndex` of columns, you can do a [`.droplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), as follows:

```
new_df = new_df.droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your column `Index` has become a `MultiIndex` because of concatenation, you should be able to reassign your columns with the first level from that `MultiIndex`

```
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.levels[0]
```